# Dual monitors - Acting like one

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce, hp-pavilion

So, I got my hands on two 32" TV screens.
My laptop is an HP Pavilion, 12 GB RAM with a Nvidia GeForce 940m, Windows 10.

The laptop has only one HDMI output (no DVI or VGA output)
so I purchased a two HDMI adapter (one HDMI to two HDMI).
But for some reason, both monitors act as one monitor;
the second monitor isn't being detected.

Unfortunately, upgrading the laptop isn't an option.
Anything to do? I have read about the USB 3.0 Port Replicator Docking Station, eGPU (not sure if eGPU will work on my laptop)
but I don't wanna spend over 150 USD without getting results.
Help?

**EDIT** 
Sorry if my question wasn't clear, I can't use extended mode for the external monitors cause the second monitor isn't detected.
I want the two external monitors to be always in extended mode (which for some reason isn't possible) with the laptop lid closed (which I managed to do) to use for games, I have read that I need to use nvidia surround but my gpu doesn't support it.

[image: Here's a picture of the adapter]

Comment: Are you complaining about the two monitors showing the same? That is the default setting (mirror) but you can change to extended or not? Your question isn't clear enough. Please [edit].

Comment: "two HDMI adapter (one HDMI to two HDMI)." --> Can you share the model/type name/number of this device?

Comment: Guessing the adapter just lets you hook up multiple screens but shows the same content which is useful in some situations.  Answering p._phidot_ will verify.

Comment: First, the displays ARE being detected because they are displaying content. So you're mis-reading something on your screen. Second, it's a given that these two external displays will show the same thing as each other because of the adapter you purchased, BUT are they also showing the same thing as the built-in monitor on the laptop? I'm guessing the answer to that is "yes" but that because of how you have worded your question, it is still unclear.

Answer (score 2):

HDMI ports cannot support multiple displays. Your adapter is most certainly a *splitter* which simply sends the port's output signal to both displays.

As long as you have a decent CPU, a USB-based video solution is your best option on a budget.

Answer (score 1):

You instlled a " (1 hdmi to 2 hdmi ) " connector.. It is exactly like connecting 1 channel audio output to two separate speaker sets..

Yes, you add the number of port.. but you won't get the 2nd channel audio output (eg.. when playing 2 different video, you may want speaker set 1 to play audio from movie 1 and speaker set 2 to playing audio from movie 2). To do that, you'll need a device that 'adds' another audio channel to your PC. Not just a port extender/replicator.

In this case, what you need is a another hdmi channel (and port). Something like [this](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812866005). It adds another separate hdmi port, with separate channel (2 separate channel, 2 separate port).

The one you own now is a single channel hdmi duplicator (1 channel 2 port), which is working as designed. ( :

> I have read about the USB 3.0 Port Replicator Docking Station, eGPU (not sure if eGPU will work on my laptop) but I don't wanna spend over 150 USD without getting results.

This is the solution you are looking for. Just to be safe.. ask the seller to demo & test with your laptop when you buy it. Or else, insist for a standard warranty.

For extended effort, you may look for a product review by recognized IT/AV magazine for the model you are looking for.

Hope it helps. ( :

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you purchased a "splitter", which does present an additional external monitor to the computer, but only one of them. Both screens connected to the splitter will show the same thing as each other, though it should be entirely possible for them to show something different from the built-in screen on the laptop. It is impossible for this device to show two different things on your two external screens, it is simply the wrong device if that is what you want.

**Second**, nVidia Surround very likely has pretty much nothing to do with what you're asking.

**Third**, I'm assuming you want the two external screens to show something DIFFERENT from the screen on the laptop. To do this you open **Settings** on your computer and navigate to **System** and then **Display**. In the Display window you scroll down to the section **Multiple Displays** and set the drop-down to **Extend desktop to this display** (or you press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to bring up a sidebar menu and select **Extend**).

**Fourth**, your computer is probably going to sleep when you close the lid. To change this you open **Settings** > **System** > **Power & Sleep**, click **Additional Power Settings**, click **Choose what closing the lid does does** and set it to **Do Nothing**.